# Issues writing unicode data to csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, unicode

I'm having trouble understanding how to write this datatype to a csv file. I'm using requests in Python 2.7 and this is coming back as `<type 'unicode'>`. This is just a snippet of the data:

```
"sizeOfApplication":0,"totalFailedFolders":0,"totalFailedFiles":0,"isVisible":true,"localizedStatus":"Running","isAged":false,"totalNumOfFiles":0,"jobId":955329,"sizeOfMediaOnDisk":0,"status":"Running","lastUpdateTime":1528140228,"percentSavings":0,"localizedOperationName":"Auxiliary Copy","statusColor":"greenspan","backupLevel":0,"jobElapsedTime":1732834,"jobStartTime":1526389208,"currentPhaseName":"Auxi"sizeOfApplication":179325630,"backupSetName":"Databases","totalFailedFolders":0,"totalFailedFiles":0,"isVisible":true,"localizedStatus":"Running","isAged":false,"totalNumOfFiles":54,"jobId":971203,"sizeOfMediaOnDisk":27870043,"status":"Running","lastUpdateTime":1527914335,"percentSavings":84.4584,"localizedOperationName":"Backup","statusColor":"greenspan","backupLevel":1,"jobElapsedTime":241877,"jobStartTime":1527897616,"currentPhaseName":"Backup","jobType":"Backup","backupLevelName":"Full"
```

When I try to set this as a literal_eval, I get a Value Error: malformed string and when I looked that up, I'm thinking its because there's decimal data in the output and that ast doesn't support decimal.

```
cvData = ast.literal_eval(str(r.text))
```

I've tried the following does not work either:

```
with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'wb') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, r.text.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w = csv.DictWriter(writerow(r.text))
```

Clearly, this is an issue between the chair and the keyboard and I apologize in advance because my python skills are quite lacking.

Is there a way to either get this to output correctly or to remove/convert the decimals (assuming that's the issue)?

Comment: The issue with writing Unicode data to CSV is explained in the docs. The short version is: Python 2's `csv` module doesn't understand Unicode, but the [Examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples) show various ways to work around it. There are multiple duplicate questions on this here, but they all basically tell you to use those examples, or to search PyPI or elsewhere for modules that essentially just wrap up those examples (one of which you don't want, because it was abandoned many years ago, which I know because I wrote it…).

Comment: Is that data supposed to be JSON by any chance? `literal_eval` seems like an overkill for parsing an API response. Moreover, what does Unicode or CSV have to do with the issue?

Comment: But meanwhile, you aren't even _getting_ that far, so I don't know why you're asking about a problem you don't have. If you can't parse your data into a dict, you can't write that dict to a CSV.

Comment: '"currentPhaseName":"Auxi"sizeOfApplication":179325630,' Looks like when you spool out the second entry, you arent properly closing quotes on your previous entry creating a malformed string that wont parse correctly as it moves on to the next element (types wont match anymore)

Comment: Also, what do you mean "there's decimal data in the output"? There isn't anything in the sample you showed that produces any errors. Please give us a [mcve] that includes the actual exception traceback, and some code that generates that exception, and enough sample data to reproduce it.

Comment: Finally: Where is this data coming from? If you're calling some API, you should know what that API is supposed to return—which is probably JSON. If it's not in the format it's supposed to be, the right answer is ideally to get the API fixed—especially if the server is written by you, or the guy in the cubicle across from yours—if at all possible, rather than to try to figure out how to parse garbage.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I'm going to try abarnert's response now and get back to you. I was hoping for json as a response but it doesn't look like its properly formatted for that. Stephan pointed out something I forgot to mention. I'm not sure what's causing that. I'm using an API from a vendor but I'm not too familiar with its intricacies.